# Tried installing Windows 10 on MacBook Pro from a USB...failed

Tags: bootcamp

I attempted to install Windows 10 Home on my son's MacBook per the instructions and assurances of others as to how simple this would be. I apologize but apparently I am a moron because not only did it not install whatsoever but now I have a single line on the screen saying "no bootable device--insert boot disk and press any key". I have no idea how to simply get back to a functioning status. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you want to keep the macOS operating system on the computer? or did you intentionally erase it?

Comment: Try to install windows 10 via an empty DVD by burning the ISO to it through disk utility. I used a DVD-R with 4.7GB of space on it and after the mac restarts when BCA finishes it should boot into the windows installer. If the problem persists just restart the mac again and hold alt as soon as it starts and you should see a boot menu it should show either EFI boot or windows whether your mac supports efi boot

Comment: What year is your MacBook Pro? I believe the newest models do not use an optical drive or USB ports to install Windows via the Boot Camp Assistant. You install directly from the Windows iso image.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Windows 10 via an empty DVD by burning the ISO to it through disk utility. I used a DVD-R with 4.7GB of space on it and after the Mac restarts when BCA finishes it should boot into the Windows installer.

If the problem persists just restart the Mac again and hold <kbd>Option</kbd> as soon as it starts and you should see a boot menu it should show either EFI boot or Windows whether your Mac supports EFI boot.

Comment: Why would this be any different than installing from USB?  Apple hasn't had a SuperDrive on a MacBook Pro since 2014

Comment: Well I can't really tell how old your mac is. Most old macs don't support USB installations for BCA unless you modify the files to make it support it in-which it might just waste your time. Have you tried holding the Option key on startup to find either 'Windows' or 'EFI_boot'?

Comment: Alternatively if you just want to get back to macOS just hold option on startup and head to macintosh